# Installed python packages can not be imported

Tags: python, import, anaconda, package

Can you guys help me with the following?

I am a beginner in programming using `python 3.6` and I try to install packages like `wget`, `pycortex`, etc. In my anaconda environment, that I created in a server.

Even though these packages seem to be downloaded (typed "`conda list`") and imported on the command window by `ipython,` they can not be imported on `Jupiter notebook` that I start in the server. Might anyone have a thought about the reason?

Comment: I would check first, whether they are listed when typing `%conda list` in the notebook. If not, you may need to have to make sure that the ipython kernel in the notebook matches the environment where you installed the packages.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, thank you.